# How to map all the orphan users in sql server management studio express 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

my target was to moved all the mssql databases from sql server management studio express 2005 server to sql server management studio express 2008  server. For this i first created the databases and the users in the new server via plesk panel. I tried logging in to the database with the created users and was able to login without any issues. But after i restore the database from the old server i was not able to login to the same database. It throws the following error:

Create failed for User 'USER_NAME'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
User, group, or role 'USER_NAME' already exists in the current database. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15023)

I googled it and found the following sql query which fixed the problem, but one database at a time. 
Here is the query syntax

USE DB_NAME
GO
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'USER_NAME', 'LOGIN_NAME’
GO

I have 100s of database and i can't do this manually for all the database. My question is.. is there any alternative to map all the orphan users to their databases?

**Update - **

**Cause of this issue**

So as far as my research goes, the issue is with the SID (  ) override after restoring the database from the source server.

Initially while creating new logins it will be assigned with a SID and once we restore the database from source server, the login will be having the new SID assigned to it by the new server and the database will have the old SID from the source server which causes the SID mismatch between the login and the database. To resolve this we use the above syntax to override the SID in the database with the SID of the login user, that way both database and login will have the same SID.

Reference:  [here](http://dbadiaries.com/how-to-transfer-logins-to-another-sql-server-or-instance)

Comment: If you still have the old 2005 instance running with the databases, then you might be able to script out the permissions from the old instance\database. Example [SQL Permissions script](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2002/object-permission-scripts/). The link have example to generate a SQL script and you may still need to do some manual work to remove lines that you may not want.

Comment: @t_m thanks for your suggestion. 'll try it. Actually due to lack of options i wrote a dummy proof script by fetching all the user_name and login_name from a text file and using loop i pasted the name is the above script and saved it in another text file and then ran it in SSMS... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your databases using the sys.databases table. If your statement is correct and it fixes your problem for one database, this should do it for all you databases and for all users

```
create table testtable
(
tid int identity(1,1) not null,
sqlstatement varchar(max) null
)


go
DECLARE @DBNAME as varchar(100)
declare @sql2 as varchar(MAX)
declare @usestat as Nvarchar(max)
declare @update as varchar(10)
declare @usern as varchar(10)
declare @loginn as varchar(10)
declare @quote as varchar(10)

DECLARE @username varchar(25)
SET @update = 'update_one '
set @usern = 'USER_NAME '
set @loginn = 'LOGIN_NAME '
set @quote = ''''
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR
    FOR select name from sys.databases where database_id >4
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor
INTO @DBNAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
set @sql2 = 'USE '+@DBNAME
------------------
set @usestat = @sql2
set @usestat = ' declare @quote2 as varchar(10) set @quote2 = '''''''' DECLARE @username as varchar(MAX) DECLARE @Statement as varchar(max) DECLARE fixusers CURSOR FOR SELECT UserName = name FROM '+@DBNAME+'.sys.sysusers WHERE issqluser = 1 and (sid is not null and sid <> 0x0) and suser_sname(sid) is null ORDER BY name OPEN fixusers FETCH NEXT FROM fixusers INTO @username WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN SET @statement ='+@quote+@sql2+' GO EXEC sp_change_users_login'+@quote+'+@quote2+'+@quote+'update_one'+@quote+'+@quote2+'+@quote+','+@quote+'+@quote2+@username+@quote2+'+@quote+','+@quote+'+@quote2+@username+@quote2+'+@quote+' GO'+@quote+' print @statement FETCH NEXT FROM fixusers INTO @username END CLOSE fixusers DEALLOCATE fixusers'
insert into testtable (sqlstatement)
values(@usestat)
-----------------
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
end
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
go
declare @statement2 as varchar(max)
declare @tidcount as int
set @tidcount = 1
while @tidcount <= (select count(*) from testtable)
BEGIN
set @statement2 = (select sqlstatement from testtable where tid = @tidcount)
exec (@statement2)
set @tidcount = @tidcount + 1
END
```

This will give you your script in the output. This will be done for all user defined databases

Comment: Thank you for the script, but it solves part of my problem. This script is good till " USE (at)DATABASE_NAME " and the remaining is just the syntax " USE DB_NAME GO EXEC sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'USER_NAME', 'LOGIN_NAME’ GO ". is there any way possible to retrieve the USER_ NAME and LOGIN_NAME??

Comment: There you go :) I've edited the script so it will do this for all your orphaned users

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. There was 2 flaws in the script, one is a minor syntax error which i have edited, other is that the user name and login name is not iterating. all the db names names have same username and login name. I tried to fix it, but ran out of clues.

Comment: Ok it was a little bit harder to configure then expected but this definitly does the trick :) Enjoy

Comment: you took this to the next level man. There is one last thing to be done in this script, which is the user name and login name should come within quotes like 'db_user1','db_user1'. I lost the flow in the quotes.. :P, i'm also trying to add the quotes, if i find success. i'll update the script.. thanks a lot for the script man..

Comment: I'll give you a new version tomorrow but can't access my ssms now :)

Comment: Subhash, the last edit is the script you need, my apologies for the long wait since the last edit, but it was a bit of a mad house here :p

Comment: you are officially the best.. :) this script is perfect. it does what i expected.. :) thanks a lot stijn. i have added line breaks in the code according to the syntax.. you made me happy:)

Comment: enjoy! I know i have to do this soon so i'll be able to use it myself! see you.next time

Answer (score 0):

you also can use SSIS transfer logins(transfer login task)from old server to new server

Comment: sorry no SSIS in express Edison.. @Hlin